# 503 Over quota - google app engine deployed site

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a website with static html/css pages that gets close to 1500 unique visitors each day. I made changes to the site after a period of 5 months using google app engine. I must have deployed 4-5 times. When I go the site, I am getting a 503 over quota error. When I checked my stats, I noticed that outgoing bandwidth is 1.01 and the maximum is 1GB per day. I have no clue what outgoing bandwidth means. I bought the domain and hosting from google apps.

Can anyone care to explain what is really going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outbound bandwidth is nothing but the bandwidth served by the google app engine to your visitor for serving web pages and other static/dynamic content.

when ever a user visit to your site and open any html page the user actually downloading the file from your site. for example your page size 10 kB and your css size is 6 kB and page contains 2 images of 100 kB each then the user downloaded totally 216 kB (100kB + 100kB + 10kB + 6kB). so if your site having 100 visitor then your site serving 216 * 100 = 21600kB (approx 21MB). Like this when ever a page loaded, google app service count the bytes which is served to your site visitor. As per you said, Your end users are using the volume more than 1 GB which is defined by Google app engine.

Comment: @MM86 you can move some static files to Google Cloud Storage, especially if it's large files, like videos. You'll get charged for Storage (I believe for less that $5/mo) though, but it's not going to hurt your free quota for app engine